# Difference between WebClient and HtmlUnitDriver in selenium?

Tags: winforms

I am working in selenium normally but now am switch over to work in Selenium back end process.So I want to know which one i want to prefer either Webclient or htmlunit driver?

Regards,
Denny.D 
QA

Answer (score 1):

By 'webclient', I guess you mean the htmlUnit webclient?
http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html

I'm not sure what you mean by 'switch over to work in Selenium back end process'. You change from selenium IDE to webdriver?

As always, the answer depends on your goal.
If it's enough for you to have an automation that runs just with htmlUnit, then use htmlUnit webclient.
But I would rather recommend htmlunit-driver. On this way you are using selenium webdriver and you hold the door open to use other browsers respectively their drivers.
Remember: HTMLUnit is way faster than other drivers, but also has some disadvantages:
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#htmlunit-driver